# Visual Studio 2015 Cannot connect to Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I have created a blank Android Native C++ project using Visual Studio 2015 Preview. When I click to run it on the emulator, the emulator will load but I always get the following error and cannot run the app on the emulator.

**3>Starting emulator...
3>Error installing the package. The device '169.254.191.177:5555' is invalid or not running.  Please switch to another device, or use the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager to start a compatible emulator, or connect a compatible Android device.
3>The device is invalid or is not running.**

Would this be because I have the Windows Phone emulator installed ? I havnt done anything except install Visual Studio 2015, create project, and run.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you need to use "adb connect 169.254.191.177:5555"

Long answer:
[Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024202/visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-issue)

Answer (score 0):

This is not likely to be a result of having the Windows Phone Emulator installed. More likely is that there is a problem with the connection between the VS Android Emulator and Visual Studio. Repairing your VS and VS Emulator for Android installations by going to **Control Panel > Programs and Features** may resolve this.