# Visual Studio Emulator for Android is frequently detached from ADB

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

[Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/20/you-can-now-acquire-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-on-its-own.aspx) works great with Android Studio. There is only one problem I am experiencing now: It is detached from ADB frequently. I can start the emulator and load an app to run without any problem. However, after a while, it is detached without any warning. Android Studio and [Android Device Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html) do not see the emulator anymore while they can always see a physical device connected to the dev machine without any problem, so I assume ADB works fine.  Restarting the emulator will restore the attachment, but it will detach again after a while. Resetting ADP does not help.

Comment: A few questions that might help: How much time is there between disconnects? Are there any particular gestures or actions that cause this? How many versions of ADB (or the Android SDK) do you have on the machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been having the exact same problem.  It's not a fix, but a workaround;  you can manually reconnect ADB to the emulator using command line:

```
adb connect <ip>:5555
```

(from [Prem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026030/3268060) on a similar question)

You can find the value for < ip > if you look in the ADB logs.  You'll probably see something similar to

> ExecutionException getting info for device **123.456.123.456**:5555

Or you can open the 'Additional Tools' of the emulator and see the Network Addresses.

Answer (score 0):

`Visual Studio Emulator for Android` is a running Hyper-V virtual machine, which was connected to your host computer using an *imaginary* cable.

Since it's an actual machine, it's normal to see it as a physical device.

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you. The physical device is a real device connected to the computer.

Comment: @Hong So you mean there're 1 physical device plugged in and the emulator running? Could you see both of them using `adb devices`?

Comment: No, that does not show it.  I have just realized it is probably a problem of the emulator.  The Device Monitor sees it now after I restarted the emulator.

Comment: This happen so frequently, so I will edit my question to describe it.

Comment: @Hong Yes, sometimes (well, a lot) the emulator won't connect to the host machine after it's boot. It happens ever since beta version. Let me know if you got a solution.