# emulator not showing up on android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I've searched all over the web for the past 3 days and can't seem to find a solution. I've done everything mentioned in this post:

[Android emulator not showing in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644144/android-emulator-not-showing-in-visual-studio)

It seems all the 'working' solutions to this problem has been stated in what this guy says he did in his original post, including restarting ADB server (kill and start), restarting my computer, reinstalling emulator and HAMX, installing and running as an admin, changing the timeout delay, reinstalling almost everything, making sure my emulator is installed, etc.

It keeps saying Gradle build finished in 475ms, etc and then waiting for target device to come online for like 5-10 minutes and nothing happens. No emulator shows up. I can't seem to find the solution to this and I am on the verge of giving up, I really need Android Studio to work so I can start on my app.

Can I please get some guidance with this?

If it's relevant, I'm using a Mac.

Comment: This may not help you as its a pretty rare case, but are you running windows 10 pro or education edition? If you are, check if HyperV is enabled, and if it's enabled turn it off.

Comment: I'm actually on mac

Comment: I've seen some answers that say to turn off Docker app when trying to run the app for mac but I don't even know what that is so I doubt I have the app installed.

Comment: What was the solution @BigDreamz ?

Comment: @DeepDave check my answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291046/7481665

Comment: @BigDreamz Thank you buddy.. 
I had to reset android studio to make it work afterall

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this. Go to the emulator settings and set the Graphics Emulation mode to Software GLES. The default mode will be automatic. I am not sure how it works, but that worked for me on two Linux machines. Being software emulation, the performance of the emulator will not be as good as when using hardware graphics. It seems to be a bug with the SDK.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me the only thing that worked in `macos` was to disable docker before starting Studio.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Wipe the data of your Android virtual Device and then start the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Android studio 4.2 and faced this issue.

No Solutions worked for me so I just erased android studio files. Updated to Android Studio Arctic Fox.
Link to remove android studio files from mac : [How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)
For Windows : [How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)