# Visual Studio Emulator Could not install smartsocket listener

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I am trying to run the Xamarin Forms Phoneword demo on Visual Studio 2015 and cannot get the app to open in the emulator.  The emulated device opens and seems to work but my app never shows up in it.

I get this error: "could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket addressw (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  (10048) ... followed by adb server errors.

I have looked for solutions for both the smartsocket error and the adb server errors, but nothing has helped.  (This is my first attempt at Android development on Visual Studio so it may be a newbie error.)

This is the VS output log:

```
1>Deploying 5.1" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Build started.
1>C:\Users\Royce.WKS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 169.254.190.187:5555 devices 
1>error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
1>could not read ok from ADB Server
1>* failed to start daemon *
1>error: cannot connect to daemon
1>List of devices attached
1>adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
1>
... 
and 46000+ characters device list.
...
1>Selected device is not running.
1>Build FAILED.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found on this thread [Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024202/visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-issue?rq=1)

The answer:

> manually connect with adb connect :5555, then retry.

That worked for me, even though the errors I was getting were not the same as what the other question described.